# How to mount docker volume on gitlab local branch?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to mount gitlab local branch folder.
Docker run command is here:

`docker run --name img -v "$(pwd)":/app test-image`

This is not working. 
I added this in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

How can I mount a gitlab branch folder to write data while running docker container?

I have been looking for help :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could make it work with the help of my colleague :-)

I am new to gitlab. Sorry, If I explained anything wrong.

**Here is my solution:**

I was trying to mount a local folder in container to create output files in local folder, that way I can view the output files.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:7
RUN mkdir /myApp
COPY myProject/  /myApp
ENTRYPOINT ["perl","/myApp/entrypoint.pl"]
```

Here I want to store my output in /app which is in docker container and I want to mount this to my local folder.I am using following command.

`docker run --name img -v "$(pwd)":/app test-image`

This is the mount point `"$(pwd)":/app` (local current working directory) but this is not creating any output in my current directory. I do not know whether this is possible to create ouput in local branch directory.

My intension to view the output file and output is a static html content. So, I solved this by using **gitlab pages**. I am mounting the gitlab **artifact** that way I can view my file in **gitlab pages**(You can create gitlab pages only for static html content).

Here is my gitlab CI file

```
pages:
 stage: deploy
 image: docker:stable
 script:
   - mkdir -p ./public
   - docker run -v "$(pwd)"/input:/source -v "$(pwd)":/output test-image -input
     /source -output /ouput/public  || true

 artifacts:
  paths:
    - public
```

Above `docker run` command is according to my requirement where I am passing command line arguments(-input and -output) to perl script in docker image.

Here important thing is **output**. We can give any names for input and output but output should be mounted on **public** which we are using as **artifact**.

Create a folder as /public in current directory and mount this as ouput. Now, you can see your output in **gitlab pages(settings->pages)**.
As I mentioned earlier we can view gitlab pages only if it is static html content which has index.html.
If you do not have index.html then you have to download the artifact and view the files. When the job completed, it will create a artifact folder. You can view this right side of your job execution.